# Is there a way to programmatically change the color of an editor tab in my Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a `SharedHeaderFormEditor` in my Eclipse RCP plugin.

One of my requirements is to draw attention to the editor's tab when something happens outside of the editor and it needs a refresh.

Some of the ideas discussed included

- changing the color of the tab
- adding an icon to the editor's text (instead of the standard * for a dirty editor)

Are either of those possible? I've been looking around and have not found anything that could address this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming this is Eclipse 4 (either e4 or e3) you could probably do the tab color using a custom tab renderer in the CSS (`swt-tab-renderer`) - but tab renderers are complex things. Adding text to the tab title (like the dirty *) would require using a renderer factory to provide a custom `StackRenderer` - again this requires studying the existing renderer to see how it works.

Comment: @greg-449 How about [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/46250/) ideea? Could he override the `IEditorInput.getName()` to add some text to the tab title?

Comment: @JohnDoe The problem is you want the text to change when something changes in the editor (like the dirty indicator changes). This isn't easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPart` and `EditorPart` both allow changing the title label and icon (`setPartName(…)` and `setTitleImage(…)` respectively).  The Eclipse Workbench also offers an `IWorkbenchPartProgressService` to each part, which allows a part to indicate that it's busy (via `incrementBusy()`/`decrementBusy()`) and that its content has changed (via `warnOfContentChange()`).  You can see this used in the *Search* and *Console* views (`org.eclipse.search2.internal.ui.SearchView` and `org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView`).